# Confusing on how to prove complex function is differentiable everywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know the relationship about complex differentiable and differentiable everywhere, actually.

From WolframMathWorld : [Complex Differentiable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDifferentiable.html),
The function is complex differentiable when $f(z)$ has derivative, has continuous partial derivative, and satisfies the Riemann Equation. It said that analytic is equivalent with Complex differentiable.

Suppose i have :

$$f(z)=\cos x \cosh y +i \sin x \sinh y$$

The function is indeed continuous since it has no singularity. But it fails on Cauchy-Riemann Equation.

Is that means it's not complex differentiable? Then, how about differentiable everywhere?

Actually the first thing i thought of before i don't know the definition when i heard "differentiable everywhere" was just involving derivative on the complex plane and has no singularity.

Comment: If it fails C-R (as this does) then it's not complex differentiable.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Actually my tittle is should be how to prove function is differentiable everywhere which the function is complex. Is differentiable everywhere the same as complex differentiable?

Comment: @user516076 complex differentiable, which implies analytical,  is stronger than real differentiable in general.

Comment: So, it's not differentiable everywhere? Please let me know where is the point is not differentiable. Thanks

Comment: Anyplace where Cauchy-Riemann fails is a place where it's not differentiable. Cauchy-Riemann is the *definition* of differentiability for functions of a complex variable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok thanks for the answer. Last question please. Could i use the limit to show that the function isn't holomorphic that implies it isn't differentiable everwhere when i take the limit along $\Re(z)$ and $\Im(z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the key to understanding the link between complex differentiability and Cauchy-Riemann equations, is to understand why the Cauchy-Riemann equations must hold.

Your last statement is exactly what it means to be complex differentiable. A function $f$ is complex differentiable at $z$, exactly when $lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ exists. Or equivalently if
$$f(z+h)= f(z) + hf'(z) + h \phi(h) $$
for some function $\phi$ satisfying that $lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\phi(h)=0$. Notice that $h$ can approach $0$ from infinitely many different paths, so complex differentiability is a much stronger criteria than regular differentiation.

Now a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is said to be differentiable at $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ if
$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + Jh + \phi(h)||h|| $$
again with $\phi$ continous at $0$ and J is a linear map (more precisely the Jacobian matrix).

If we have a function $f=(u,v)^T$, then for $\tilde{f}=u+iv$ to be complex differentiable, the equations above suggests that $J$ needs to correspond to multiplication by a complex number. But how does multiplication of complex numbers look as linear maps on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Since $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+cb)i$, we get for the vectorized computations that
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} ac-bd \\ ad+cb \end{pmatrix}$$
Now plugging in the definition of the Jacobian gives
$$J=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{du}{dx} & \frac{du}{dy} \\ \frac{dv}{dx} & \frac{dv}{dy} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b  \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} $$
which gives us exactly the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Differentiability is a local property. The notion of being differentiable everywhere simply means that the function is differentiable at all points.

Comment: Hi, what do you think about my function? Is it not differentiable everywhere? Thanks

Comment: The question has somewhat been answered in the other answer, but just to clarify:
If you say that a complex function is "differentiable everywhere", then from the context it has be interpreted as "complex differentiable everywhere", hence cauchy-riemann equations must hold everywhere. 
Saying that $(Re(f),Im(f))$ is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a different statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to write something about the geometric intuition.

A complex function $f(x+iy)$ could be viewed as a function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $F(x,y) = (u(x,y),v(x,y))$ where $u,v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations say that $f$ is complex differential at a point $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$ iff $F$ is differential at $(x_0,y_0)$ AND the Jacobian matrix $J$ of $F$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ represents a 'conformal' linear transformation (i.e., if $\vec{a},\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $\angle(\vec{a},\vec{b}) = \angle(J\vec{a},J\vec{b})$).

A reason for this, is that if $f'(z_0)$ is defined then it is a complex number $a + ib$ and $f(z_0 + \Delta z) - f(z_0)$ can be approximated by $(a+ib)\Delta z$. Multiplication by $(a+ib)$ could be viewed as a linear transform on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then it is clear from Euler's formula that such a linear transform is a composition of scalar multiplication and rotation, thus 'conformal'. Conversely, by easy linear algebra, any conformal linear transformation on the plane is of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so can be represented by a complex number.

As for $f(x+iy) = \cos x \cosh y + i \sin x \sinh y$, the corresponding $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is differential on the whole plane and at a point $(x,y)$ has a Jacobian matrix like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin x \cosh y & \cos x \sinh y \\
\cos x \sinh y & \sin x \cosh y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is not conformal at every $(x,y)$.

Comment: *As for $f(x+iy) = \cos x \cosh y + i \sin x \sinh y$, the corresponding $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is differential on the whole plane and at a point $(x,y)$* . So, my function is differentiable everywhere but it's not complex differentiable? Sorry for my retard.

Comment: Then complex differentiable is different with differentiable everywhere? is that so?

Comment: @user516076 $f$ being complex differentiable at $z = x + iy$ is different from the corresponding $F$ on the plane being differentiable at $(x,y)$. An extra condition ($J$ being conformal) is needed.

Comment: Ok, then it's just differentiable at Real plane right? Not in the complex plane?

Comment: @user516076 You may say so, if you identify $f$ with $F$.

Comment: Thanks it's really clear know. :)